# TeX in comments

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re-render MathJax in comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/re-render-mathjax-in-comments)

When it shows "2 more comments" (and you press the icon) for example, the TeX disappears and we are left with code between dollar signs.

Comment: This is just http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012/re-render-mathjax-in-comments

Comment: This is definitely an issue.  However, we only want one copy of the issue open.